# plane cubic with a singularity must have non-constant morphism from $\mathbb{P}^1$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, projective-space

If $C$ is a plane projective curve which is defined by an irreducible homogeneous cubic polynomial and has a singularity, why must there be a nonconstant morphism $\mathbb{P}^1\rightarrow C$?

(I'm not sure whether $C$ is supposed to have *exactly* one singularity; is the result still true if it has more than one?)

I think the proof should look something like this:

> let $\alpha$ be the projection map from a singularity $P$ of $C$ onto $\mathbb{P}^1$. This is a rational map of degree 1 (why?), so it has an inverse rational map $\alpha^{-1}$ from $\mathbb{P}^1$ to $C$ (why?), which must be a morphism since $\mathbb{P}^1$ is smooth.

But there's two points I can't prove! If we choose coordinates so that $P=[0:0:1]$, then $\alpha([x:y:z])=[x:y]$, so $\alpha$ has domain $C\backslash\{P\}$, and its degree is the sum of ramification indices and therefore at most 3; but why must it be 1? Then given a rational map of degree 1 between two projective curves, why does it need to have a well-defined inverse?

Many thanks for any help with this!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your rational map in effect projects $C$ to the line at infinity $z=0$ of $\mathbb P^2$.
It has degree one because given a point at infinity $A$ the line $AP$ cuts $C$ in exactly one point distinct from $P$, for all but at most three values of $A$.
The inverse rational map $\alpha^{-1}$ is indeed defined everywhere since the line at infinity is smooth.
So $\alpha^{-1}\colon \mathbb P^1\to C$ is a normalization of $C$.
As to your last question, a birational map does *not* need to have   as inverse a morphism: $\alpha^{-1}$ furnishes a counterexample.
And finally, as an answer to your parenthatical remark,  yes a cubic can only have one singularity.
Else the line joining two singularities would cut it in at least four points, contradicting Bézout.

Comment: I didn't follow your second sentence - why can't $AP$ cut $C$ in 2 points other than $P$? Since $A$ is a point at infinity and $P$ is the origin, $AP$ must have equation in the form $y=\lambda x$ (affine coordinates). Substituting that into the (cubic) equation for $C$ gives an equation in $x$ of degree at most 3 - why can't there be 3 distinct roots?

Comment: Dear Harry, any line cuts your irreducible  cubic curve in exactly $3$ points, with the *caveat* that you have to take multiplicities into account. Now any line through $P$ already cuts the cubic with a multiplicity at least $2$ at $P$, so that it can only cut the curve in *one* more other point. In other words, the equation of degree $\leq 3$ in $x$ you mention will already have a double root at $x=x_P$ and can only have one more root. Why not try to make all this explicit on the example $y^2z-x^2z-x^3=0$ (a node) after having drawn a picture ?

Comment: Ah, OK: because $P$ is singular, the line through P must be tangential. Thanks for the answer! +1